# Entropy solution with non convex flux with derivative invertible just almost everywhere

Tags: partial-differential-equations, entropy, hyperbolic-equations

I have to discuss the entropy solution to the following initial value problem

$
\begin{cases}
u_t+f(u)_x = 0 \\
u(x,0) = u_0(x) = \begin{cases}
u_{-},\quad x<0\\
u_+,\quad x>0
\end{cases}
\end{cases}
$

where the flux function is $f(u) = \sqrt{|u|}$. I just have a question about the case $|u_+|<|u_-|$ and $u_-u_+\geq 0$ where, in order to satisfy the Oleinik entropy condition, it should happen that the segment joining the 2 points $[u_-,f(u_-)]$ and $[u_+,f(u_+)]$ should be over the graph in order to say that the unique entropy condition is a shock wave moving with speed given by Rankine Hugoniot condition, *which is not our case*. So my idea is to propagate a rarefraction wave solution of the kind:

$
\begin{cases}
u_-,\quad x<f'(u_-)t \\
(f')^{-1}(x/t),\quad f'(u_-)<x/t<f'(u_+) \\
u_+,\quad x>f'(u_+)t,
\end{cases}
$

but the problem is that I cannot invert everywhere the derivative of the flux function but just almost everywhere since even the derivative is not defined everywhere.

How should I solve this problem?

By the way here is the plot of the geometric representation of Oleinik condition in the case I'm interested in: $0\leq u_+ \leq u_-$

[image: Geometrical interpretation of Oleinik entropy condition]

---

**UPDATE**
I think I've managed to solve the case in which for instance $0<u_+\leq u_-$, where the derivative is well defined and being a monotone function is even invertible. My solution is the following:

$
u(x,t) = \begin{cases}
u_-,\quad x/t<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u_-}} \\
\frac{t^2}{4x^2},\quad \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u_-}}<x/t<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u_+}} \\
u_+,\quad x/t>\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u_+}}
\end{cases}
$

obtained as usual by self similarity of solutions to conservation laws with flux function smooth enough, like the one obtained by restricting the domain of such a a function to the $u>0$.

But of course now the problem still remains since if I fix $u_+=0$ I don't know how to solve the Riemann problem with an arbitrary $u_->0$.

Maybe I should focus on the weak formulation so that the derivatives of the flux function are deloaded on some smooth test function but I really don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Without thinking more deeply about this, I'd say you're basically done. You can just formally take the limit $u_{+}\to 0$ in your formula, no? Or why doesn't $u(x,t) = u_{-}$ for $x/t < 1/(2\sqrt{u_{-}})$ and $u(x,t) = t^2/(4x^2)$ for $x/t > 1/(2\sqrt{u_{-}})$ provide a solution for $u_{+} = 0$?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this case as a limiting case, but I'm really not sure if this formal procedure is actually right. Do you have any source where I can study a similar example @Sam ?

Comment: I don't have a similar example at hand. But you don't really have to show that this formal procedure works. All you have to do is check that the limiting $u(x,t)$ is an weak entropy solution, from the definitions (integration against a test function etc.). My bet would be that there is not problem.